# Cast from an Object ArrayList to Object Array in JSP

Tags: java, arrays, list, jsp, arraylist

I am trying to do a simple conversion from ArrayList to Object Array but I am getting an error, I have tried numerous methods as mention on the internet but none of them is working, NEED HELP

Here is what I am doing

```
  private List<CartItems> cartobj = new ArrayList<CartItems>();

  --- Bean (Cart) ---

  private String name;
  private float price;
  private int quantity;

  --- In Servlet ---

  Order h = new Order(String a, String b, String c);
  cartobj.add(h);

  session.setAttribute("Cart", cartobj);


  --- In JSP ---

  <tbody>
      <% ArrayList<CartItems> cartobj = new ArrayList<CartItems>();
      cartobj.add((CartItems)session.getAttribute("Cart"));
      for(int i=0;i<cartobj.size();i++)
      {%>
          <tr>
              <td><% out.println(i+1); %></td>
              <td><% cartobj.get(i).getProductName(); %></td>
              <td><% cartobj.get(i).getPrice(); %></td>
              <td><% cartobj.get(i).getSales_Address(); %></td>
              <td><% cartobj.get(i).getOrder_Date(); %></td>
              <td><% cartobj.get(i).getQuantity(); %></td>
          </tr>

      <% } %>
```

I also tried this

```
     <% 
       CartItems[] obj = (CartItems[])session.getAttribute("Cart");
       for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
       {%>
           <tr>
               <td><% out.println(i+1); %></td>
               <td><% obj[i].getProductName(); %></td>
               <td><% obj[i].getPrice(); %></td>
               <td><% obj[i].getSales_Address(); %></td>
               <td><% obj[i].getOrder_Date(); %></td>
               <td><% obj[i].getQuantity(); %></td>
           </tr>
       <% } %>
```

I am getting this following error

```
  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Final_Project] threw exception [java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [LObjects.CartItems;] with root cause
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [LObjects.CartItems;
    at org.apache.jsp.cart_jsp._jspService(cart_jsp.java:165)

Comment: What about `List<CartItems> obj = (List<CartItems>) session.getAttribute("Cart")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast a `List` to an array. A `List` is not a type of array. But, you could use [`List.toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29) and change

```
session.setAttribute("Cart", cartobj);
```

to something like

```
session.setAttribute("Cart", cartobj.toArray(new CartItems[cartobj.size()]));
```

then

```
CartItems[] obj = (CartItems[])session.getAttribute("Cart");
```

would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it to List like this:

```
List<CartItems> obj = (List<CartItems>) session.getAttribute("Cart");
```

Still better to use [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) for directly iterating on your list of objects:

```
<c:forEach items="${Cart}" var="element"> 
 <tr>
   <td>${element.productName}</td>
   <td>${element.salesAddress}</td>
   <td>${element.quantity}</td>
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And follow Java bean naming conventions for your setters and getters, for example, getSales_Address is not a correctly defined.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `List<CartItems>` to session, `ArrayList` can not be cast with `Array`.

Try the following:

```
  <% 
   List<CartItems> obj = (List<CartItems>)session.getAttribute("Cart");
   for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
   {
     CartItems cartItem = obj.get(i);
   %>
       <tr>
           <td><% out.println(i+1); %></td>
           <td><% cartItem.getProductName(); %></td>
           <td><% cartItem.getPrice(); %></td>
           <td><% cartItem.getSales_Address(); %></td>
           <td><% cartItem.getOrder_Date(); %></td>
           <td><% cartItem.getQuantity(); %></td>
       </tr>
   <% } %
```

Avoid java code in your jsp as much as you can. You can achieve this using `JSTL`.

```
<c:forEach items="${Cart}" var="c" varStatus="loop">
    <tr>
        <td>${loop.index+1}</td>
        <td>${c.productName}</td>
        <td>${c.price}</td>
        <td>${c.sales_address}</td>
        <td>${c.quantity}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```